# PHP 7 и laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, php7

После апгрейда до php 7.0.4, laravel стал ругаться что нет функции

> Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\mb_internal_encoding()

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\mb_internal_encoding() in ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php:43

Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/safari/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(183): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application))
#1 /var/www/safari/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(199): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#2 /var/www/safari/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(110): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->bootstrap()
#3 /var/www/safari/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(84): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#4 /var/www/safari/public/index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#5 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/safari/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php on line 43


php -v
PHP 7.0.4-7+deb.sury.org~trusty+2 (cli)

php -m | grep mb
mbstring

php -r 'echo mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8").PHP_EOL;'
1
```

Answer (score 3):

Уже была такая проблема

Ссылка на баг трекер: 
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6891

Обсуждалась тут: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/call-to-undefined-function

Comment: Благодарю, но ошибка оказалась в другом.
После установки php-mbstring я просто не перезапустил апач.

Comment: Там как раз об этом и писали)

Answer (score 0):

После установки php7.0-mbstring, необходимо было перезапустить апач